# Terraform : how to provide multiple lambda fucntion zip files in a single resource block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules, terraform-aws-modules

working snippet for 1 lambda function. Terraform version 0.14.9.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "main" {
     function_name = var.lambda_name
     role          = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn
     handler       = "index.handler"
     runtime       = "nodejs12.x"
     filename      = "testlambda1.zip"
}
variable "lambda_name" {
  default = "testlambda1"
}
```

I am new to terraform. I have total 4 lambda functions in zip format.  How to provide all of them in 1 resource block.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "main" {
      function_name = var.lambda_name
      role          = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn
      handler       = "index.handler"
      runtime       = "nodejs12.x"
      filename      = var.filename
}
variable "lambda_name" {
   type    = list(string)
   default = [
             "testlambda1",
             "testlambda2",
             "testlambda3",
             "testlambda4"
             ]
}
variable "filename" {
   type    = list(string)
   default = [
             "testlambda1.zip",
             "testlambda2.zip",
             "testlambda3.zip",
             "testlambda4.zip"
             ]
}
```

I tried this but ended up with the error.

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main-lambda.tf line 6, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "main":
   6:   function_name = var.lambda_name

Inappropriate value for attribute "function_name": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main-lambda.tf line 10, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "main":
  10:   filename      = var.filename

Inappropriate value for attribute "filename": string required.
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a "requirement" of your infra, but it doesn't look good to me. Have you checked the official lambda module? https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest -- Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single resource block to create multiple resources you need to use the Terraform [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html), or [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) meta-arguments.

For example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "main" {
      count         = length(var.lambda_name)
      function_name = var.lambda_name[count.index]
      role          = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn
      handler       = "index.handler"
      runtime       = "nodejs12.x"
      filename      = var.filename[count.index]
}

variable "lambda_name" {
   type    = list(string)
   default = [
             "testlambda1",
             "testlambda2",
             "testlambda3",
             "testlambda4"
             ]
}

variable "filename" {
   type    = list(string)
   default = [
             "testlambda1.zip",
             "testlambda2.zip",
             "testlambda3.zip",
             "testlambda4.zip"
             ]
}
```

or converting your variables into a map, and using `for_each`:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "main" {
      for_each      = var.lambdas
      function_name = each.key
      role          = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn
      handler       = "index.handler"
      runtime       = "nodejs12.x"
      filename      = each.value
}


variable "lambdas" {
   type    = map(string)
   default = {
             "testlambda1" = "testlambda1.zip",
             "testlambda2" = "testlambda2.zip",
             "testlambda3" = "testlambda3.zip",
             "testlambda4" = "testlambda4.zip"
             }
}
```